# Yum PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"

Tags: domain-name-system, yum, dig

I am attempting to redo my server (CentOS release 6.6 [Final] x86_64) and I am now getting the following output on `yum`

```
[root@server ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Setting up Update Process
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Because it's relevant here is my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver IP ADDRESS
nameserver IP ADDRESS
search au.sever.com vmware.au.server.com
```

This is an output for a `dig`

```
[root@server ~]# dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I have also run `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` and it appears to have run sucessfully

Additionally my `/etc/named.conf` file is empty. I don't know why and/or what to put in it...

I can't ping google.com either...

Comment: First thing to do would be to connect it to the Internet.

Comment: It's a vps and I am connecting to it via SSH, I am assuming this means it's internet connected. (I don't mean for that to sound facetious)

Comment: What do you get when you try resolving `mirrorlist.centos.org` specifically?  Also, does your /etc/resolv.conf literally have two lines that read `nameserver IP ADDRESS`?

Comment: Hi @MikeB When I ping `google.com` the output is `ping: unknown host google.com` I assume the same would be for `mirrorlist.centos.org` and I removed the IP Address. Upon further investigation, it appears to be my internal IP Address.

Comment: @Joshua So you can't reach any sites?  It sounds like it's not a DNS issue - it just can't connect at all. What do you have set under `/etc/sysconfig/network`?  Is `GATEWAY=` set to the right IP for your default router/gateway?  If you're not sure, I'd check with your VPS host.  They should be able to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out my problem my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` was incorrect `bootproto` was set to `none` or something similar, I changed it to `static` then rebooted and everything came online.

Comment: Type `ifdown eth0`
`ifup eth0`

Comment: Just a heads up to other users reading this comment, Do **NOT** use command `ifdown eth0` if you are working on a remote web server through ssh